# How do I do the null check using Optional

Tags: java

I have following method

```
public static String convertThreeLetterWordToUpper(String str) {
    String result = Arrays.stream(
            str.split(" ")).map(s-> checkLength(s)).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    return result;
}
```

How can I check if str is not null with out performing a null check and return Optional of result.

Comment: I think throwing an exception here is more clear here, you can't convert something non-existing to something existing

Comment: You could accept here as well? Btw: welcome to *upvote* levels ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the orignal string in [`Optional.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-). Assuming checkLength returns a string, the return type of the below would be `Optional<String>`.

```
Optional.ofNullable(str)
    .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(" "))
                .map(string -> checkLength(string)) 
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

If you have a default return value to return you can just chain `orElse()` or can throw an exception with `orElseThrow()`.

```
String result = Optional.ofNullable(str)
     .map(...)
     .orElse("someDefault");
     //.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException()); Or whatever makes sense
```